# SwaggerDecorator not working after update API Platform to v2.3.5

Tags: api-platform.com

After the API platform upgrade, the decorator from the documentation has stopped working:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-swagger-documentation

Does anyone know if this is a change, is it a bug?

I use Symfony 4.2.2 (**probably the problem is due to the Symfony update**).

My code adding to swagger input form to change context:

```
<?php
namespace App\Swagger;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

final class SwaggerDecorator implements NormalizerInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        $customDefinition = [
            'name' => 'context',
            'definition' => 'Context field',
            'default' => '',
            'in' => 'query',
        ];


        // Add context parameter
        foreach ($docs['paths'] as $key => $value) {
            // e.g. add a custom parameter
            $customDefinition['default'] = lcfirst($docs['paths'][$key]['get']['tags'][0] ?? '');
            $docs['paths'][$key]['get']['parameters'][] = $customDefinition;
            if(isset($docs['paths'][$key]['post'])){
                $docs['paths'][$key]['post']['parameters'][] = $customDefinition;
            }

            if(isset($docs['paths'][$key]['put'])){
                $docs['paths'][$key]['put']['parameters'][] = $customDefinition;
            }

        }

        return $docs;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use parameter "decoration_priority" in services configuration (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html#decoration-priority)

For example:

```
App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator:
    decorates: 'api_platform.swagger.normalizer.documentation'
    arguments: [ '@App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator.inner' ]
    decoration_priority: 1000
```

Or fix version "symfony/dependency-injection": "4.2.1" in composer.json )

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29836 for details